# How to handle this session condition?

Tags: asp.net

After login,user is redirected to default page.I apply break point on pageload.Break point work.On clicking logout hyperlink,it will redirect to the sessionclear page.After loging out,when I am entering page name,it will redirect to login page.I am checking session in every page and master page also.Whem I am putting defaule page,it redirect to default page.I am not able to see execution of break point.Why this happening?

Comment: show some piece of code you are using .

Comment: Please give the code for defaultpage which you are executing also tell the line on which you are putting the breakpoint.